# Autostop page from loading after 10 seconds

Tags: javascript

I have advertisements and scripts that run on my forum, and sometimes the page continues to load forever because those scripts aren't loading on time (i.e. Facebook, Adsense). Does anyone have a JavaScript that would automatically stop the page from this continuous load after, say, 10 seconds?

Comment: How can you be sure that your page will be loaded in 10 seconds? What if the user has poor internet connection/speed?

Comment: What other means would you suggest then? Those pesky ads - while they generate money, they suck at loading...

Comment: One way is to put all the JavaScript code for ads and everything at the end of the page.

Comment: Right, but what if the ad is at the very top of the page, wouldn't make sense.

Comment: Position of the ad doesn't matter. If you put JS code for it at the end, it will not be visible unless its JS loads, and the page will be loaded first, then the ads.

Comment: So, move this part

<script type="text/javascript"
            src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
    </script>

to the end of the page?

Comment: You can use .preventDefault() method on your event. This will stop the default action of a page .

Comment: Add the code for adsense etc in `ready` function. So that ad will be displayed when page is ready.

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
   //code here
});
will run a script when the document structure is ready, but before all of the images have loaded.

if you want to run script before the document structure is ready, just put your code anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

How can you be sure that your page will be loaded in 10 seconds? What if the user has poor internet connection/speed?

What I would suggest you is to put the JavaScript of advertisements and tracking (anaylytics) etc at the end of the page. Or if you can use jQuery then put this in `ready` function, so that when the document/page is ready, then you start calling JS functions for advertisements and all.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  // your code goes here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add js:

```
setTimeout(window.stop,10000);
```

Comment: So...

   <script>setTimeout(window.stop,10000);</script>

Comment: yes, but do not add it in onLoad) also it`s not a good idea cause just slow internet can be...